# How to understand sys.stdout and sys.stderr in Python

Tags: python

I have the following simple Python code.

```
stdout = sys.stdout
stderr = sys.stderr

try:
   # Omitted

finally:
  sys.stdout = stdout
```

After searching, I found that *sys.stdin*, *sys.stdout*, and *sys.stderr* are file objects corresponding to the interpreter's [standard input](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_input_(stdin)), [standard output](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_.28stdout.29) and [standard error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_error_(stderr)) streams. So, my guess here is that we first assign the *sys.stdout* and *sys.stderr* to the variables *stdout* and *stderr*.

Then, even if there are exceptions in the *try* statement, can we always get the *sys.stdout* back? Is this correct? I felt that I was still confused.

Comment: No matter what happened in what case? It's not clear what you're asking or trying to accomplish

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In normal C programs, there are three "files" open by default: stdin, stdout, and stderr.  When you do input and output in C, by default they come from stdin and stdout.  But, you can also use them where code expects files, or reassign them to be new files.

Python seeks to "mimic" this behavior of C.  When you `print()` in Python, your text is written to Python's `sys.stdout`.  When you do `input()`, it comes from `sys.stdin`.  Exceptions are written to `sys.stderr`.

You can reassign these variables in order to redirect the output of your code to a file other than stdout.  This is very similar to [shell redirection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_%28computing%29), if you're familiar with that.  The reason you might do something like this is to keep a log of your program's output or make code "shut up", i.e. not send output to stdout.  So, in your example example:

```
stdout = sys.stdout

try:
    sys.stdout = open('file.txt', 'w')
    print('blah')
    # etc
finally:
    sys.stdout.close()  # close file.txt
    sys.stdout = stdout
    sys.stderr = stderr
```

This code wouldn't print anything to the console, but it would write "blah" to a text file named `file.txt`.  To make this sort of thing less error-prone, Python provides `sys.__stdin__` and `sys.__stdout__`, which always hold the original values of `sys.stdin` and `sys.stdout`.  The above code could be made simpler using this:

```
try:
    sys.stdout = open('file.txt', 'w')
    print('blah')
    # etc
finally:
    sys.stdout.close()  # close file.txt
    sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
```

The reason Python has both `stdout` and `__stdout__` is mainly for convenience, so you don't have to make a variable to back up `stdout`.

**However,** I have to recommend that you don't make a habit out of reassigning `stdout`.  It's pretty easy to mess things up that way!  If you want to save your code's output, you can use shell redirection.  If you want to have the ability to keep a log of what your program is doing, see Python's [logging](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/logging.html) module.  If you want your code to be quieter, give your functions a `quiet=False` parameter so you can shut them up when you want!  There is rarely a "genuine" need to do reassign `stdout`, etc.  Python allows you to do it, because Python gives programmers a lot of control, and expects them to be responsible.  You could do something like this, if you really wanted to:

```
>>> import random
>>> random.random = lambda: 1
>>> random.random()
1
>>> random.random()
1
```

Comment: So, what is the difference between 'sys.stdin' and 'sys._stdin' in python ?

Comment: I updated the answer a lot with more information.  I accidentally gave you bad info... it's `__stdout__`, not `_stdout`!  Also, the difference is really that `print()` uses `stdout`, and `__stdout__` is there as a backup in case you "lose" the original value.

Comment: Help me understand when things are written to the screen. You say " Exceptions are written to sys.stderr.". BUT, when my code crashes it always prints to the terminal...does that mean that displaying to the terminal come from the union of content from `sys.err` AND `sys.stdout`?

Answer (score 0):

About the link you sent for the logging module, it seems to be deprecated (which is almost guaranteed after more than 8 years). Here should (hopefully) be the right link for the [logging](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html) module.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).