# Printing in Python before exception, output unordered

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, printing, output

The output of the following python program my be occasionally out-of-order:

```
print("Dividing 0 by 0...")
res = 0/0
```

->

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "[...]/scratches/scratch_8.py", line 2, in <module>
    res = 0/0
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
Dividing 0 by 0...
```

After I read the following threads: [Disable output buffering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107705/disable-output-buffering), [How can I flush the output of the print function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230751/how-can-i-flush-the-output-of-the-print-function) and [Python's print function that flushes the buffer when it's called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3895481/pythons-print-function-that-flushes-the-buffer-when-its-called),
I changed my program into:

```
print("Dividing 0 by 0...", flush = True)
res = 0/0
```

However, it still prints the output occasionally out-of-order. Why is the `flush = True` option not showing it's effect?

Comment: Are you confused about the first line is not executed? that's kind of amazing.
Maybe you should paster the whole content flushed by the terminal.

Comment: The first line is always executed. However, the output comes occasionally after the exception message. I understand that python IO is buffered, therefor I included `flush = True`. But what I do not understand is, why it still not works.

Comment: `print` and exception message are using different streams, `stdout` and `stderr`. Exception message should be unbuffered too, probably that's why occasionally it doesn't work. Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59719872/why-does-python-print-exceptions-to-the-console-before-print-output), you can consider writing to standard error if it fits your requirement.

Comment: Even if adding `sys.stderr.flush()` before `res = 0/0`, the output is still occasionally out-of-order. I read the program including the line above in the following way: 1.) Print a msg, then flush the `sys.stdout` stream. 2.) Flush the `sys.stderr` stream, 3.) Raise exception, output exception msg to `sys.stderr`. Stream not flushed. Why is this still out of sync? Don't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is the `flush = True` option not showing its effect?

Because exception stack traces [**are not written to** the same place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31420317) as `print` output, by default. The `print`ed message is sent to the program's standard output stream (`sys.stdout`), while errors appear on the standard error stream (`sys.stderr`).

To get consistent output order, these streams [need to be **synchronized**, not just flushed every time there is an output.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68498635).

Comment: I would close this as a duplicate, but the other question doesn't have an answer yet.